# jQuery match only part of id from div

Tags: jquery

I ran into an unusual situation yesterday night.

I need to match only part of id. Let me clear you all with an example

I have few divs like

```
<div id="sales_info_1">... ...... ...... ...... ...</div>
<div id="sales_info_2">... ...... ...... ...... ...</div>
<div id="sales_info_3">... ...... ...... ...... ...</div>
```

and jQuery goes like

```
jQuery("div#dont_know_what_to_write_here").bind("click", function(){
    ... ...... ...... ...... ...
});
```

I need to match only **sales_info**, ignoring _1, _2 or _anything, can anyone suggest me how to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to bind the click event on all div's which have id sales_info_<number>?

Comment: @all: thanks all for your suggestions/solutions

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You could use the ["Starts With" selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('div[id^="sales_info_"]')
```

I'd rather recommend you use a unique class name for your elements that you can select on though.

Comment: Why do you recommend that?

Comment: Because it simplifies the whole thing and is more semantic. Classes explicitly specify that the element is a *type of thing*, while similarly named ids only imply this in the best case.

Comment: similarly is there a way to ignore a particular id during a partial select ?

Comment: I know this is really late, but to exclude a particular id, you could do something like

$('div[id^="sales_info_"]:not( #specific-id )')

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, add `class="sales_info"` to your HTML mark-up.

Then, do this:

```
$(".sales_info").bind("click", function() {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$('div[id^="sales_info"]').bind( ... );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try with this

```
$("div[id^='sales_info_']").bind( ... );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css selector

try this code

html

```
<div id="sales_info_1"></div>
<div id="user_info_1"></div>
<div id="sales_info_2"></div>
<div id="user_info_2"></div>
<div id="sales_info_3"></div>
<div id="user_info_3"></div>
```

css

```
.red{
    display:block; 
    float:left; 
    width:50px; 
    height:20px; 
    background-color:#FF0000;}
.blue{
    display:block; 
    float:left; 
    width:50px; 
    height:20px; 
    background-color:#0000FF;}
```

jquery

```
$('div[id^="sales"]').addClass('red');
$('div[id^="user"]').addClass('blue');
```

css selector `^=` will select div with ID that start with the specified value and add the css style.

Answer (score 1):

I actually needed the `end-with` effect and found it [here](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).
It's easily used as follows:

```
<script>
$( "input[name$='letter']" ).val( "a letter" );
</script>
```

You just replace the `^` with `$` in the selector.