# get dynamically created textbox id jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery for dynamically creating html code using for loops, i need to get the **ID** of the dynamically created img, how could i get the **ID**?

here is the jquery code

```
var subscriptionDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'subscription' + counter);
             subscriptionDiv.html('<div class="form-group">'+
                                    '<div class="fieldBlock">'+
                                        '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                                            '<label for="meal" class="col-lg-2 control-label" style="width: 138px;">Date: '+dateArray[j]+'</label>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                   '<div class="fieldBlock">'+
                                      '<label for="meal" class="col-lg-2 control-label" style="width: 138px;">Meal Option:</label>'+
                                      '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                                            '<select class="dropdown rightside" id="meal1-'+mealArray[i]+'-'+counter+'" name="meal-'+counter+'" style="width: 220px;">'+
                                                 '<option value=""></option>'+
                                                 '<option value="Breakfast" id="b">Breakfast</option>'+
                                                 '<option value="Lunch" id="l">Lunch</option>'+
                                                 '<option value="Dinner" id="d">Dinner</option>'+
                                            '</select>'+
                                      '</div>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                   '<div class="fieldBlock">'+
                                             '<label for="breakfast" class="col-lg-2 control-label" style="width: 120px;">Breakfast</label>'+
                                       '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                                             '<select class="dropdown fieldBlockta" name="hrs-'+counter+'" style="width: 55px;" id="hrs-'+counter+'">'+
                                                    '<option value="hrs">hrs</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="0">0</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="1">1</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="2">2</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="3">3</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="4">4</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="5">5</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="6">6</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="7">7</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="8">8</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="9">9</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="10">10</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="11">11</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="12">12</option>'+
                                             '</select>'+
                                             '<select class="dropdown fieldBlockta" name="mins-'+counter+'" style="width: 65px; margin-left: 20px;" id="mins-'+counter+'">'+
                                                    '<option value="mins">mins</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="0">0</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="1">1</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="2">2</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="3">3</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="4">4</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="5">5</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="6">6</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="7">7</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="8">8</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="9">9</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="10">10</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="11">11</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="12">12</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="13">13</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="14">14</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="15">15</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="16">16</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="17">17</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="18">18</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="19">19</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="20">20</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="21">21</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="22">22</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="23">23</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="24">24</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="25">25</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="26">26</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="27">27</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="28">28</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="29">29</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="30">30</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="31">31</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="32">32</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="33">33</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="34">34</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="35">35</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="36">36</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="37">37</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="38">38</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="39">39</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="40">40</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="41">41</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="42">42</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="43">43</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="44">44</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="45">45</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="46">46</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="47">47</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="48">48</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="49">49</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="50">50</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="51">51</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="52">52</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="53">53</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="54">54</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="55">55</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="56">56</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="57">57</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="58">58</option>'+
                                                    '<option value="59">59</option>'+
                                             '</select>'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                   '<div class="fieldBlock">'+
                                       '<label for="location" class="col-lg-2 control-label" style="width: 138px;">Location:</label>'+
                                       '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                                           '<select class="dropdown rightside" style="width: 220px;" id="location-'+counter+'">'+
                                               '<option value=""></option>'+
                                               '<option value="Office">Office</option>'+
                                               '<option value="Residence">Residence</option>'+
                                               '<option value="GirlFriend">Girl Friend</option>'+
                                           '</select>'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                   '<div class="fieldBlock">'+
                                       '<label for="address" class="col-lg-2 control-label" style="width: 245px;">Address plus instruction for delivery</label>'+
                                       '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                                           '<textarea class="textarea" id="address-'+counter+'" required="required" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="Address plus instruction for delivery"></textarea>'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                   '<div class="fieldBlock">'+
                                   '<div class="form-group">'+
                                       '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                                           '<img id="add-'+counter+'" style="height:30px; margin-top:30px;" src="/images/add.png"/>'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                   '<div class="form-group">'+
                                       '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                                           '<img id="minus-'+counter+'" style="height:30px; margin-top:30px;" src="/images/minus.png"/>'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                   '</div>'+
                                   '<div class="fieldBlock">'+
                                       '<div class="col-lg-10">'+
                                           '<button type="button" id="subscribeNow-'+counter+'" name="subscribeNow-'+counter+'" class="btn btn-primary subscribeNow" style="">Save & choose eatery</button>'+
                                       '</div>'+
                                   '</div>');
                                    $('select option[value="meal1-'+mealArray[i]+'-'+counter+'"]').attr("selected",true);
             subscriptionDiv.appendTo("#subscribe");
             counter=counter+1;
             }
             }


        });
```

I need to get the id of the img source which is dynamically created

```
<img id="minus-'+counter+'" style="height:30px; margin-top:30px;" src="/images/minus.png"/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery match only part of id from div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4743860/jquery-match-only-part-of-id-from-div)

Comment: how do you want to get it? on click event?

Comment: @Arjun: One thing to note whenever creating dynamic elements is that you have to query for them only after making sure it has been injected into the DOM. This is just an FYI cos i had faced similar issues with dynamic elements due to not knowing this.

Comment: @Gourav yup on click event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

```
     $('.form-group img').each(function(){
        alert(this.id);
     })
```

Comment: I am not getting every id of the img some id's are missing

Comment: it will only get id of image which are child of .form-group element.if you want other image than change your selector

Comment: in that form-group only image is there but I m not getting every id of the img

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('img[id^="minus-"]').each(function (i,el) {
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   // or what ever you want to do with this element/s..
   var counter = $(this).attr('id').match(/\d+/g);
   if ( counter[0] == 10 ) {
       // do something for the img with id `minus-10`
   }
});
```